# React Native-Firebase:How To turn off data auto sync when reconnected?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I im using background location function , that update current location data to firebase. when it run, if network is dropped , firebase automatically caching location changes and upload rapidly  when reconnect with firebase server. how i disable this? . I just want update current changes not cached data ...

this is a simple tracking app, its get location data and upload to firebase. and show location realtime on map. when cached updates fire rapidly web user  see, tracking object jumping around map thats the problem :/

```
timerlocationfunction(location)=>{
    var connectedRef = firebase.database().ref(".info/connected");
    connectedRef.on("value", (snap) => {
        if (snap.val() === true){
            adaNameRef.update({ lat: location.latitude, lng: location.longitude, isConnected: "true" });
            firebase.database().goOnline();
        }else{
            firebase.database().goOnline();
        } 
    });
}
```

i tried `firebase.database().purgeOutstandingWrites();` but app give error 'undifned is not function'

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need a function `purgeOutstandingReads()` which doesn't exist.

I too have the same problem you have described here. When logging back into the database after being disconnected for several days, the realtime database sends all the interim transactions. I only want the latest transaction. (I am using the database to store a single colour pixel from a webcam sent once per second. Bit by bit a picture is formed. I do not want hundreds of old colors included. )

This is descibed as a key capability of Firebase Realtime Database here
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/

> Offline : Firebase apps remain responsive even when offline because the Firebase Realtime Database SDK persists your data to disk. Once connectivity is reestablished, the client device receives any changes it missed, synchronizing it with the current server state.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the client ignore the iterim data by timestamping all data, and then when you re-log in you save the first timestamp you receive. From then on only use data which has a timestamp greater than your saved timestamp.

You can timestamp the data on the firebase server by adding this to any data object.

```
  timestamp: firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP
```

This will just be a large number like 1638212892432.

However you will still be paying for the interim data you are downloading and not using.

I don't see a way to turn this off.